# Populate variable in a grouping in R

Tags: r

I have this `DF`:

```
DF_1 <- data.frame(ID = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C ","D","D","D"),
                 PROC = c("11","22","33","44","55","66","77","88","99","10","20","30 "),
                 COLOR = c("OK","OK","OK","OK","PENDING","OK","PENDING","PENDING","PENDING","OK","OK","PENDING "))
```

I want to group the variables `ID` and `PROC` to check if there is any `"PENDING"`, if so, the new variable `"FINAL"` should be filled with `"PENDING"`, otherwise `"OK"`.

This is the result I want:

```
DF_1 <- data.frame(ID = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","D" ,"D","D"),
                 PROC = c("11","22","33","44","55","66","77","88","99","10","20","30 "),
                 COLOR = c("OK","OK","OK","OK","PENDING","OK","PENDING","PENDING","PENDING","OK","OK","PENDING "),
                 FINAL = c("OK","OK","OK","PENDING","PENDING","PENDING","PENDING","PENDING","PENDING","PENDING","PENDING","PENDING "))
```

I tried this code, but it didn't work:

```
  DF_1 <- DF_1 %>%
   group_by(ID, PROC) %>%
   mutate(FINAL = ifelse("PENDING" %in% COLOR, "PENDING", "OK")) %>%
   ungroup()
```

I don't know how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping by `PROC` in this case is making it a row-wise operation, I suggest you remove that.

Side note, one of your `COLOR` is has a trailing space in it; either that should be removed (if a mistake) or we need to use `trimws` or `grepl` to work around it.

(I defined your second example as `DF_2`, including the desired `FINAL` column.)

```r
DF_2 |>
  group_by(ID) |>
  mutate(FINAL2 = if (any(grepl("PENDING", COLOR))) "PENDING" else "OK") |>
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 12 × 5
#    ID    PROC  COLOR      FINAL      FINAL2 
#    <chr> <chr> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>  
#  1 A     "11"  "OK"       "OK"       OK     
#  2 A     "22"  "OK"       "OK"       OK     
#  3 A     "33"  "OK"       "OK"       OK     
#  4 B     "44"  "OK"       "PENDING"  PENDING
#  5 B     "55"  "PENDING"  "PENDING"  PENDING
#  6 B     "66"  "OK"       "PENDING"  PENDING
#  7 C     "77"  "PENDING"  "PENDING"  PENDING
#  8 C     "88"  "PENDING"  "PENDING"  PENDING
#  9 C     "99"  "PENDING"  "PENDING"  PENDING
# 10 D     "10"  "OK"       "PENDING"  PENDING
# 11 D     "20"  "OK"       "PENDING"  PENDING
# 12 D     "30 " "PENDING " "PENDING " PENDING
```

Alternates, with various fixes:

```r
### if it should not have a trailing space
DF_2 |>
  mutate(COLOR = trimws(COLOR)) |>
  group_by(ID) |>
  mutate(FINAL2 = if ("PENDING" %in% COLOR) "PENDING" else "OK") |>
  ungroup()

### if a trailing space is meaningful and you need to preserve it,
### you can use the `grepl` above or use this
DF_2 |>
  group_by(ID) |>
  mutate(FINAL2 = if (any(c("PENDING", "PENDING ") %in% COLOR)) "PENDING" else COLOR) |>
  ungroup()
```

Another side note: if you instead want to keep the original value of `COLOR` (if it could contain other values), then the `ifelse` will not work correctly since it will return the same length vector as found in its first `test=` argument. For instance, see

```r
ifelse(TRUE, 1:2, 3:4)
# [1] 1
```

and since your `"PENDING" %in% COLOR` is returning length-1 `TRUE`, you're running into that logical problem. In your case, both your `yes=` and `no=` are length-1 vectors, so we don't see this symptom, but you should be aware of this behavior nonetheless

---

Data

```r
DF_2 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D"), PROC = c("11", "22", "33", "44", "55", "66", "77", "88", "99", "10", "20", "30 "), COLOR = c("OK", "OK", "OK", "OK", "PENDING", "OK", "PENDING", "PENDING", "PENDING", "OK", "OK", "PENDING "), FINAL = c("OK", "OK", "OK", "PENDING", "PENDING", "PENDING", "PENDING", "PENDING", "PENDING", "PENDING", "PENDING", "PENDING ")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Thanks. But I necessarily need PROC to be in group_by

Comment: If you must group by `PROC`, then how are you going to know there are `"PENDING"` within the same `ID` but different `PROC`?

Comment: Your data has 12 unique rows by `ID, PROC`, so your expected output is counter-intuitive when grouping by both. Perhaps explain what `PROC` has to do with this step.

Comment: Thanks. I understand your worries. In the internal process that I am having difficulties with, I need to group it with PROC.

Comment: Your question is currently under-explained or inconsistent. There is no way to get `"PENDING"` for (say) `B,66` when its only color is `"OK"`, yet that's what you have in your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

in base R use `ave`:

Note that `'PENDING' > 'OK'`. We therefore can get the `max` of the two in a group

```
transform(DF_1, FINAL = ave(COLOR, ID, FUN = max))

   ID PROC   COLOR   FINAL
1   A   11      OK      OK
2   A   22      OK      OK
3   A   33      OK      OK
4   B   44      OK PENDING
5   B   55 PENDING PENDING
6   B   66      OK PENDING
7   C   77 PENDING PENDING
8   C   88 PENDING PENDING
9   C   99 PENDING PENDING
10  D   10      OK PENDING
11  D   20      OK PENDING
12  D   30 PENDING PENDING
```

---

tidyverse:

```
DF_1 %>% 
   mutate(FINAL = max(COLOR), .by = ID)

   ID PROC   COLOR   FINAL
1   A   11      OK      OK
2   A   22      OK      OK
3   A   33      OK      OK
4   B   44      OK PENDING
5   B   55 PENDING PENDING
6   B   66      OK PENDING
7   C   77 PENDING PENDING
8   C   88 PENDING PENDING
9   C   99 PENDING PENDING
10  D   10      OK PENDING
11  D   20      OK PENDING
12  D   30 PENDING PENDING
```

Comment: Thanks. Through the tidyverse package it should be grouped by ID and PROC. I need it to be grouped by these two variables

Comment: @BrunoAvila and still you expect the results to be as given? Go ahead try doing so ie `DF_1 %>% mutate(FINAL = max(COLOR), .by = c(ID, PROC))` and see what happens

Comment: @BrunoAvila change your example to include duplicated PROC for a given ID. eg let ID A have PROC 11,11,11,22,22,33,33 and not just one value per row

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work out. The result was the same as the code I tried.

Comment: I thought I could use code to replace rows, but I don't have enough knowledge.

Comment: @BrunoAvila it does not make sense to include PROC in group if the data looks exactly as given above. Note that  there is only one B 66 combination in the data. And this combination has OK.. you cannot change it to PENDING.

Comment: @BrunoAvila this has nothing with knowledge. Its all about logic. Hink of cats and dogs. If a house has a cat indicate so. in one house there is only a dog. You cannot expect to indicaye that the house has a cat. Unless you change your definitionof what a house is. Here the group is compared to a house. Now look at how you would group your data to get the expected results.